# Erro ao migrar de localhost para servidor online

Tags: php, codeigniter

Ao fazer a migração de uma aplicação em codeigniter de localhost para o servidor aparece me o seguinte erro

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Warning Message:
>   session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home/bassgrou/public_html/centro_eventos/application/config/mimes.php:1)
>   Filename: Session/Session.php Line Number: 140

Backtrace:

> File:
>   /home/bassgrou/public_html/centro_eventos/application/controllers/Cliente_controller.php
>   Line: 7 Function: __construct
>
> File: /home/bassgrou/public_html/centro_eventos/index.php Line: 292
>   Function: require_once

Comment: Normalmente nunca usei session_start() para iniciar agluma coisa no CI, você está usando?

Comment: tenho autoload da libraria  'session'

Comment: Use `session_start();` de preferência como primeira função do seu arquivo, e nunca depois de ter impresso ou exibir conteúdo em HTML.

Comment: Resolvido, era um espaço em branco antes da abertura da tag <?php no ficheiro mime.php

Comment: Boa tarde, não coloque respostas dentro da pergunta, não somos um fórum ou coisa do tipo, somos um Q&A, leia o tour: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour a sua pergunta foi duplicada porque na outras respostas da outra pergunta já tem a solução pro seu problema. Tenho certeza que vai entender isto como uma critica construtiva.

Answer (score 1):

Esse erro ocorre porque você está iniciando a sessão após já ter enviado dados para o navegador.

Ao definir uma session você está criando um cookie na maquina cliente com o id da sessão por meio de cabeçalho HTTP, logo, se já tiver enviado dados para o navegador, o header já foi fechado e enviado, assim não pode solicitar o início da session.

Como solução você pode colocar o session_start logo no início do seu código,ou definir a diretiva session.auto_start no php.ini para true ou no .htaccess se estiver rodando num servidor Apache. Essa regra faz a sessão iniciar automaticamente,sem precisar utilizar o session_start()